# You are welcome

Tags: idioms

In response to "Thank you", one usually says, "You are welcome". Can this phrase be shortened and just say, "Welcome"?

Comment: Although *some* native speakers might reduce their response to the single-word form, you should be aware that if you say it with an obviously non-native accent, many people would simply assume you didn't know any better (rather than classifying you as a very attentive and conscientious learner, with your finger on the pulse of idiomatic usage).

Comment: This question appears to be generating a lot of controversy!  We have a lot of native speakers saying "yes, this is common and acceptable" and a lot of native speakers saying "no, this is not common or acceptable".

Comment: I can tell you this is extremely common ( more common than "you're welcome") in some regions where I have lived ( eg. southeast asia ) and rare in others ( parts of america and england ), but not to the point of sounding awkward or genuinely confusing.  In Australia, I heard mostly "no worries/problem", never "welcome".

Answer (score 6):

> You're welcome.

can be shortened to just

> welcome

but more often

> pleasure *(BrE)*
>   no problem

get used.  "Welcome" by itself is most often used as a greeting.
As in most circumstances intonation and context are key.

Here is an interesting take on why one should not say "you're welcome" but instead

> [I know you’d do the same for me.](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/adam-grant/pay-it-forward_b_4270340.html)

Comment: "Pleasure" gets used in BrE as a shortened for of "my pleasure".

Comment: ?!  This may be a regional difference, but if I said "Thank you" to someone, and they replied "Welcome", I would immediately think that person was a non-native speaker.  In the northeastern US at least, it is most certainly *not* common to just reply "Welcome."

Comment: @stangdon Also from the same area, and I have definitely heard just “welcome” as short for “you’re welcome.” The key is that it has to sound like “you’re welcome” without the “you’re,” which is different (in... tone? maybe? not sure of terminology) from “welcome” used to greet someone entering your home or what have you.

Comment: @stangdon I agree with you, I'm from the southeastern US, but have travelled all over the US.  The image that popped into my mind when I thought of replying to "Thank You" with just "Welcome" was a toddler who was still learning to speak.

Comment: The less formal, "welcome" should probably be something like "yu' welcome", where the "you're" is not emphasized or even finished. More breathed than said. 
Similarly, "no problem" would probably be said "no prob'" in casual settings.

Comment: @Kevin - Are you sure you're not just referring to somebody mumbling and slurring it so much the "You're" is barely audible?  I mean, I've heard people say "Have a nice day" in such a lazy way it's more like "h'nice'y", but I wouldn't say that this means that means that *the phrase can be shortened to "h'nice'y"*.

Comment: @stangdon, I was agreeing with you that just saying "Welcome" is non-standard in US English

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry, I meant to reply to KRyan and got the wrong K!

Comment: Uh… Peter… ’pleasure’ is appropriate in exactly the same way as ‘welcome’ and no other, ever. Both are abbreviations and should really be used only with people to whom respect doesn’t need to be shown; ie, close friends and relatives or people you don’t much care about. ‘It’s my pleasure’ and ‘you are welcome’ have no relevantly different meaning, and evolved through precisely the same process…

Comment: Uh… Peter… ‘Welcome’ by itself is used as a greeting but that’s not to say that ‘welcome’ as a greeting is in away except spelling comparable to ‘welcome’ as an abbreviation for ‘you’re welcome’ as a response to ’Thanks…’ It’s not.

Comment: Uh… Peter… ‘I know you’d do the same for me’ could very well be appropriate in some circumstances but vastly more often, and always in the way that link suggests, it would be a cynical attempt at manipulation, amounting to nothing more than dishonesty and I soncerely hope everyone who uses it that way, is seen for what he is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it's informal and can come off as terse or insincere, depending on the recipient.